# webkitDeprecatedPeerConnection Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, p2p, webrtc

I want to make a video platform.
I am experimenting with **WebRTC**, running nodejs as a server.
Now the problem is that I have **Chrome 21** in Ubuntu goes as it should, no errors at all, but in **Chrome 23** (in Windows), I hace an error at client side.

Here is my code

```
if(typeof webkitPeerConnection === 'function') 
    pc = new webkitPeerConnection("NONE", onSignalingMessage);   
else 
    pc = new webkitDeprecatedPeerConnection("NONE", onSignalingMessage);
```

The error happens to try to use the function webkitDeprecatedPeerConnection. It says webkitDeprecatedPeerConnection is an undefined function, it means, it does not exists.

Also, **PeerConnection** flag is enabled.

```
Linux Ubuntu 12 (32 bits) 
Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bits)
```

> *PS: Excuse me for my english, my native language is Spanish.*

Answer (score 1):

You can see that [webkitDeprecatedPeerConnection is no longer supported on Chrome](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/discuss-webrtc/tdAKZ36hHQA/discussion), right now!!

> We now have a new W3C editor's draft to work with. This draft, which
>   can be found at http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html ,
>   makes it possible for us to move forward with our implementation of
>   PeerConnection.
>
> To keep the code base manageable, we will be removing
>   DeprecatedPeerConnection from the API. This change will affect Canary
>   and Dev versions soon. The newer JSEP API provides greater flexibility
>   and allows for easier encapsulation of other protocols. A lot has been
>   written about it.
>
> For those that want a quick transition to the new API, we recommend
>   using the ROAP to JSEP JS library created by one of our colleagues. It
>   abstracts DeprecatedPeerConnection while using the newer JSEP API. It
>   can be found here:
>   http://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Froap-jsep
>
> Thanks,
>
> /Serge

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm thinking I'll implement Flash, RED5 or something like that.